# Superconductors, batteries, and the cold?

Tags: charge, electrical-resistance, superconductivity

I'm taking a calculus-based physics course: electricity and magnetism course. We touched on the concept of superconductors and how resistivity changes in relation to temperature.

Everyone knows batteries suffer in very cold winter weather. I couldn't help but wonder if this had any theoretical impact on the charge contained in a battery. While I understand that the *primary* cause of this reduced battery life is a result of slowed chemical reactions inside the cell, does even the coldest of winter weather have any impact on a battery due to a reduction in resistivity of the terminals, and loss of charge to the moist winter air? Or is the majority of charge loss due to other factors such as chemical or physical?

Comment: Either this was a stupid question, or there isn't an immediate answer without experimentation.